# how does express server work with wepback middlewares to enable hot reloading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, middleware

I'm just learning about node, express, and webpack and feel somewhat confused about middleware. Looking at the code below, my understanding is that after I start the web server and open up http://localhost:7770/ the browser issues a get request to the server which is going to go through the 2 middlewares and create a `bundle.js` in a `dist` directory in memory. Then the request hits the below:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

which will send the `index.html`, which in turn will request `bundle.js` in the `dist` folder. The `webpack-hot-middleware` listens for any changes that are saved to a file and automatically builds a new bundle to be hosted on the server. Is this correct? I'm not entirely sure when the middlewares are invoked - when a request is made or when a change (and save) is made to the code?

**devServer.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config.dev');

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(7770, 'localhost', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:7770');
});
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/pokeapp'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // js
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
      },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with what webpack modules you're using and if they include a livereload server or not.

Based on what you wrote, this is what is probably going on:

1. Middleware is run when the server receives a request from the client
2. I believe webpack is generating your 'bundle.js' and whatever other files on-the-fly when the client request comes through.
3. The client will not necessarily know that it should look for changes to bundle.js.

Looks like you're using this for development purposes. If so, [this tutorial for gulp/nodemon/livereload](http://jpsierens.com/tutorial-livereload-nodemon-gulp/) might accomplish what you're trying to do.